# Upper bound of a series

Tags: calculus

If I have $L_1+L_2+L_3+ \cdots+L_N=\bar{L}$, how can I get the upper bound of $\sum_i\frac{\bar{L}}{L_i}$? I tried to use $\sum_ia_i=1$ and bound $\sum_i1/a_i$ but failed. And $L_i$ has lower bound.

Comment: L's are some real numbers different than 0, right?

Comment: Yes. They are positive and real.

Comment: I don't yet understand the question.  Do you have an infinite sequence $L_1,L_2,L_3,\ldots$ for which you want the upper bound of the set$$ \left\{ \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{\bar L}{L_i} : N\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\} \right\} \text{ ?} $$That would mean as $N$ varies and you get a different $\sum_i \bar L/L_i$ for each $N$?  Or are you doing something similar with a finite sequence?  Or do you mean $N$ is fixed and the sequence $L_1,\ldots,L_N$ varies and you're wondering how big you can make $\sum_i \bar L/L_i$ by changing the sequence? Or something else? $\qquad$

Comment: Hi. N is fixed.

Comment: ok, So $N$ is fixed. Are you asking what's the biggest you can make $\sum_i \bar L/L_i$ by varying the sequence $L_1,\ldots,L_N$? $\qquad$

Comment: Yes, definitely!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no upper bound for $\sum_i \frac{\bar{L}}{L_i}$. Instead, you can get a lower bound by using the inequality of arithmetic and harmonic means.

Answer (score 0):

With the edit to the question, assuming there is a (feasible) lower bound to $L_i$ of $b>0$, the maximum value will be achieved with as many elements as possible equal to that lower bound.

So  for example supposing $\bar L = 2, N=5 $ and $b=0.1$ then $L_i=(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,1.6)$ will give the maximal sum of $81.25$.